# Regression fitting to climate data

Tags: regression, climate

[image: Hexbin Plot of Temperature and Precipitation]

I am trying to fit regression model between temperature and precipitation. I have three cluster of precipitation and corresponding temperature (showing in the plot). Can anyone suggest me please which regression (parametric or non-parametric) I can use for this condition !

Comment: There are many tools available, your choice should depend upon what is the exact aim of your analysis? What are you going to use it for?

Comment: Actually I am doing downscaling of precipitation. So my aim is build a relationship between historical data (Precipitation and Temperature)and apply it to the future data !